# change dropdown list to its original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have two dropdownlists in my view. by changing the value on the first one i can change the value on the second one. in the first run it works fine using scrip below. 
but when i change the first dropdownlist to something else it will not work. i believe if i can change the second dropdownlist value and text and .... rest to its original state it will be ok.
here is my code :

```
<select id="ddlDepartment">
            <option selected disabled>اselect department</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option value="@item.DepartmentTitle">@item.DepartmentTitle</option>
            }
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>grade</td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlgrade">
            <option selected disabled="disabled">Select Grade</option>
            <option id="id_bachelor" value="bachelor">bachelor</option>
            <option id="id_Masters" value="Master">Masters</option>
            <option id="Doctorate" value="Doctorate">Doctorate</option>
        </select>
```

and here is my script :

```
$('#ddlDepartment')
    .change(function() {
        debugger;
        var ddlDepartment = $('#ddlDepartment').val();
        var grade = $('#ddlgrade').val();

        getGrade();

        function getGrade() {
            $('#ddlgrade')
                .change(function() {
                    grade = $('#ddlgrade').val();
                    $.ajax('/AdminPages/showStudents/' + ddlDepartment + '/' + grade)
                        .done(function(data) {
                            $('#lstStudents').html(data);
                        });
                });
        }
    });
```

i get the erro here:

```
if ( !( eventHandle = elemData.handle ) ) {
            eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {

                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
                    jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `getGrade()` function outside. `getGrade()` function bind a `change` event handler for `second` select **EVERYTIME** you changed the first `select`.

Final Solution

```
$('#ddlgrade').change(function() {
     var ddlDepartment = $('#ddlDepartment').val();
     var grade = $(this).val();
     if(ddlDepartment){
         $.ajax('/AdminPages/showStudents/' + ddlDepartment + '/' + grade)
              .done(function(data) {
              $('#lstStudents').html(data);
          });
     }
     else{
        alert("Please select department first!");
     }
});
```

Please take a look how works your code:

```js
$('#ddlDepartment')
    .change(function() {
        var ddlDepartment = $('#ddlDepartment').val();
        var grade = $('#ddlgrade').val();
        alert(ddlDepartment);
        getGrade();
        function getGrade() {
            $('#ddlgrade')
                .change(function() {
                    grade = $('#ddlgrade').val();
                    alert(grade);
            });
        }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlDepartment">
            <option selected disabled>اselect department</option>
            <option val="1">acb</option>
             <option val="1">acfdb</option>
        </select>

        <select id="ddlgrade">
            <option selected disabled="disabled">Select Grade</option>
            <option id="id_bachelor" value="bachelor">bachelor</option>
            <option id="id_Masters" value="Master">Masters</option>
            <option id="Doctorate" value="Doctorate">Doctorate</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: @HossainEhsani, i will update my answer in few second with a solution for this.

Comment: when you change the value of the first dropdownlist, by changing the value from the second one you will get alert for the amount of times that the second dropdownlist value changed. for example if i select acb from the first ddl and select master from the scond ddl on the next run if i select something else it the it will alert 2 times

Comment: @HossainEhsani, i uodated my answer with a solution and a little validation.

Comment: i still get that error in "scrip block[dynamic]" when i want to select a value from the 2nd ddl for the second time

Comment: i remove the variables from $('#ddlDepartment')
        .change(function()  and put them in $('#ddlgrade').change(function) that way it will work. i will select your answer as best answer for this problem. but please edit it.